# Force https:// with Angular's default .htaccess file

Tags: angular, .htaccess

Angular provides a default `.htaccess` file [in its documentation](https://angular.io/guide/deployment#production-servers):

```
RewriteEngine On

# If an existing asset or directory is requested go to it as it is
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# If the requested resource doesn't exist, use index.html
RewriteRule ^ /index.html
```

However, this does not force `https://`.

Whatever I try (using answers or snippets from similar questions about https:// forcing), it always breaks the routing, and results in either `404` or the `Apache is functioning normally` notice.

---

**How do I update this snippet to force https://, while keeping the routing intact?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this

```
RewriteEngine On

# Force https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# If an existing asset or directory is requested go to it as it is
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# If the requested resource doesn't exist, use index.html
RewriteRule ^ /index.html
```

Comment: That seems to work, dankjewel! Initially this resulted in 404 too, but I think the problem was that I tried it on my dev environment, without https configured. On production, it works great!

Comment: seems to be valid but got the too many redirects errors.